# How to point cmake to zlib include path?

Tags: cmake, build, directory, zlib, minizip

Or any include directory/library.

I use cmake gui tool so I run it and usually the gui will highlight the include or library it can't find and let you open a open dialog to set the path however it doesn't do that for this cmake cofig it tell you in red text in the output in the gui tool, so,

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message):
  Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:343 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:101 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

So still using the gui how do I point cmake to the zlib include dir?

Answer (score 26):

Quick solution: **apt-get install zlib1g-dev**

Comment: or `yum install zlib-devel zlib-static` on CentOS

Comment: the OP is obviously on Windows

Comment: This is not a valid solution and does not work on Windows WSL with Ubuntu distro.

Answer (score 20):

I'll first assume you have ZLib installed somewhere, and my guess is that it's in a non-standard location since CMake find it. If that's true, you can set the location in CMake-gui. You'll need to first click the 'Advanced' checkbox near the top, because the FindZLIB.cmake file has the following line "mark_as_advanced(ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)".

Now you should be able to see the ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR options and set the correct path.

Comment: How to pass it without the GUI? (what does the GUI do actually - where is this stored? Or does it just work for generating build via GUI, and the options are passed to `cmake` command?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, if you are just calling `cmake src_dir`, you can a a list of arguments with a -D prefix. In this case, it would be `cmake -DZLIB_LIBRARY=/lib/path -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=/include/path src_dir`

Comment: I do not understand. I entered source folder path, build folder path, then clicked 'Advanced'... and nothing happend, the main listview is empty. Where exactly I should be able to see ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR options?

Comment: Those variables will only show up if one of your CMakeLists.txt files calls `FindPackage(ZLIB)`. Otherwise, your build won't know it needs zlib until you get a link error. The FindPackage call is also the only way to automatically have the library name set for you correctly. With it, you can use `${ZLIB_LIBRARY}` rather than just hard-coding `z` in your target_link_libraries call.

Comment: 只有ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR 需要 Advanced选项。

Answer (score 6):

For future googlers, according to the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindZLIB.html):

> An includer may set ZLIB_ROOT to a zlib installation root to tell this module where to look.

Answer (score 4):

When you make and build `zlib` library, you need `zlib.lib` static library and `zlib.h` and `zconf.h` header files to make `minizip` libray.

So, after building `zlib` you have the following that are need for `minizip` :

- `zlib.lib` in Release or Debug folder.
- `zlib.h` and `zconf.h` header files in `zlib` root directory.

Now set <kbd>DZLIB_LIBRARY</kbd> and  <kbd>DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR</kbd> like this :

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -A Win32 -DZLIB_LIBRARY="zlib-master\Release"  -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR="zlib-master"
```

This solution does worked for me when i need minizip library and hope this could help you.

Comment: How I can force cmake to choose static lib instead of dynamic one?

Answer (score 2):

To add to Elhanan Ilani's answer (for any novices, like myself), this should be declared near the top of the CMakeLists.txt file. For example:

```
set(ZLIB_ROOT /home/foo/zlib-1.2.11/)
set(CURL_ROOT /home/foo/anaconda3/)
```

Answer (score -1):

in my case, set ZLIB_ROOT, ZLIB_LIBRARY

```
c:\zlib - include
        - lib
```